# Efficient array access as multiple types

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, casting

I am using entity framework and need to store some binary data. I am doing this with success using a byte array and some helper methods to return the data in other formats.

I am doing this like so.

```
public class TestData
{
    public double SampleRate { get; set; }

    public byte[] ExtensionBytes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides easy access as floats instead of bytes
    /// </summary>
    public float[] ExtensionValues
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new float[ExtensionBytes.Length / sizeof(float)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(ExtensionBytes, 0, result, 0, ExtensionBytes.Length);
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[value.Length * sizeof(float)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(value, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
            ExtensionBytes = result;
        }
    }
}
```

It works but seems very wasteful, in C I would probably use something like

```
(float*)&byte_array)
```

Which seems a neater solution that means data isn't being copied back and forth in memory all the time.

Is there a similar neat solution in c#

Alternatively a way to store a float or double array in entity framework.

Comment: I would say no would be the answer, I'm interested if somebody comes with a better solution. One thing you can do though is to cache the float result in a variable and clear it whenever the ExtensionBytes is set in case this property gets called multiple times in order to avoid recreating the float every time get is called. Its an optimization, not the answer, hence I stuck to a comment :)

Comment: if you didn't know, you can use pointers in C# with unsafe option

Comment: thats a good article:
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.ru/2013/03/how-to-convert-byte-to-short-or-float.html btw conversion times dont differ much

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the scope of the variable that works with the array of floats, you might be able to use the 'fixed' keyword to pin the byte array in memory while you cast it to a float* and do your work on it. Something like this (syntax may be off):

```
fixed (byte* b = &theByteArray)
{
    var f = (float*)b;
    // do your work on f...
}
```

This would require that you mark your assembly as 'unsafe' in the project's properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think Sumit is correct, however depending on other requirements, you could implement a class that implements something like `IEnumerable`, `IList` or `ReadOnlyCollectionBase` (or a minimal subset) that would virtually expose your collection in the way you need it to.  e.g.

```
public class VirtualFloatArray
{
   public byte[] ExtensionBytes {get;set;}
   public int Length { return ExtensionBytes.Length / sizeof(float); }
   public float this[int index]
   {
      get 
      {
         var result = new float[1]{};
         Buffer.BlockCopy(ExtensionBytes, index * sizeof(float), result, 0, sizeof(float));
         return result[0];
      }
   }
}
```